# Unable to initialize const unordered_map<string, variant<int, float>> using initializer list

Tags: c++, c++17

So here is the function:

```
void spawn(const param &para) {
   // ...
}
```

The `param` is `typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::variant<int, float>> param;`

And here is how i call it:

```
spawn({{"x", 450}, {"y", 324}, {"vel", 1.0}, {"increaser", 0.05}, {"direction", 120}});
```

And here is the error:

> no instance of constructor "std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_map [with _Key=std::string, _Tp=std::variant<int, float>, _Hash=std::hash< std::string >, _Pred=std::equal_to< std::string >, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::variant<int, float>>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: ({...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...})

If I change `param` to `initializer_list`, it works but I would need to convert it into `param` later on. If I use `make_pair`, it returns another error.

So how can I fix this problem?

I'm currently using GCC 11.0 and VSCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value type of your `unordered_map` is `std::variant<int, float>`, but in your brace init list, you're passing `float` instead of a `double`. This conversion from `float` to a `variant` is not allowed.

Either change your value type to `std::variant<int, double>`, or pass literals of `float` type, e.g. `1.5f` instead of `1.5`.

The minimized issue in code is

```
std::variant<int, float> v = 1.5f;  // ok
std::variant<int, double> v = 1.5;  // ok
std::variant<int, float> v = 1.5;   // error
```